# RAID 5 - Server having 5 SATA HDD of 750 GB and 1 SATA HDD of 1TB size , will this combination support for RAID 5 and will RAID 5 work?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, raid-5

RAID 5 Configured on IBM Server, having 6 SATA HDD of 750 GB each/7.2K. Now we have one 750GB disk failure and we have replaced it by new SATA HDD but of 1TB size/7.2K. Wanted to know  will this combination support for RAID 5 and will RAID 5 work?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that different implementations such as on your "IBM Server" may act differently. Without knowing the exact model of your server there's no guarantee the controller will work exactly like this.

As a rule you want to keep the same size and model of disk within a RAID 5 array. Your controller should allow a 1TB drive to be added, but it's only going to use 750GB of the drive. While you can add larger drives, RAID 5 will only use space on each disk equal to the smallest drive.